# How to use a white logo on a white background?

Tags: branding

I have a problem. Our logo looks terrible in any colour other than white. I should say that part of the logo needs to stay white. This presents a tremendous difficulty when it needs to look professional on a white background. What are the ways around it?

I have a limited space area, but I don't want to show that limited space, therefore an idea where something is placed behind the white logo is possible, but it needs to disappear without a harsh stop.

Comment: Hi Kris - Does your company's brand have any other colors? And what is meant by the "limited space area", would you be able to share a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Kris, welcome to UX.Stackexchange. However, this question might be better suited for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow, fast answers - thank you both! I will try graphicdesign, greenforest thanks.

Comment: I can share a screenshot yes. This is our logo, but the time has come for it to need to be in a 600x180 limited space on a white background.
https://gyazo.com/9c59bbdc5d49d93c4c4e87e5c085adcf

Comment: The problem is that 'MED' and the stick figure need to stay white. They look terrible in any other colour and it's become set in stone over the years. Other than slap a bevel and a drop shadow on it, I'm not sure what else we can do.

Comment: I think this is a GD question, not a UX question. I'd change the white to green, outlined in white where it crosses the "B", and leave the green brace white (or maybe outline that in green).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White-on-white, even with a drop shadow, is low in contrast and not recommended for accessibility reasons. Logos usually have variants for this reason - in your case, there might be a green and white version, an all-green version, an all-black version, and an all-white version. If the background absolutely must be white, you'd propose using the all-green or all-black logo.

Typically, though, organizations would rather change the color of their website background than use a variant logo. You might try making a few versions and seeing which ones are easiest for users to see and understand, then present the data to your stakeholders.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer! Unfortunately changing the colour of the website background is not an option. It's EBC for Amazon. Modules underneath it are wider than the space permitted for brand logo that sits on top. So it looks daft if we keep it overlaid on anything other than white.

Might need to introduce an off-colour white, but we're not happy about it. Hindsight is a wonderful thing I guess, but we're stuck with it now.

Comment: If you’re able to alter the logo colors, I would strongly suggest a darker color (gray, black) in place of the white.